# Timer tool missing on visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer, ide

I want to implement a timer, however the timer tool is missing when I check my toolbox. How can I attain the timer?

Comment: What type of application you are creating and which version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a WPF application, the timer is not anymore an UI element. Instead you can use a *DispatcherTimer*.

Use it like this:

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer(); 
dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); 
dt.Start();
```

Read more [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/timer-in-wpf/).